# Why isn't unreachable code detected when an if condition is a constant?

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, unreachable-statement

I'm studying for a Java exam and came across the "unreachable statement" compiler error, e.g:

```
Source.java:10: error: unreachable statement
       System.out.println("This code is not reachable");
```

Am trying to understand when this would or wouldn't happen - e.g. it **doesn't** happen for these cases:

```
// Case #1
if (true) {
    System.out.println("This code is reachable");
} else {
    System.out.println("This code is not reachable"); // Compiles OK
}

// Case #2
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (true) continue;
    System.out.println("This code is not reachable"); // Compiles OK
}
```

It seems the compiler isn't smart enough to detect when the `if` condition is constantly `true` - could someone provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: The analysis appears to be [complete but unsound](http://www.pl-enthusiast.net/2017/10/23/what-is-soundness-in-static-analysis/) so it may miss errors but the ones it does give are never false. This is a design choice of the analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification, [14.21. Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) (emphasis by me):

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because
>   it is unreachable.
>
> This section is devoted to a precise explanation of the word
>   "reachable." The idea is that there must be some possible execution
>   path from the beginning of the constructor, method, instance
>   initializer, or static initializer that contains the statement to the
>   statement itself. The analysis takes into account the structure of
>   statements. **Except for the special treatment of `while`, `do`, and `for`
>   statements whose condition expression has the constant value true, the
>   values of expressions are not taken into account in the flow analysis**.

So while the code is indeed unreachable, the compiler explicitly does not regard it as such. The reason stated is to allow programmers to define "flag" variables such as

```
static final boolean DEBUG = false;

if (DEBUG) { x=3; }
```

It should be possible to switch `DEBUG` between `false` and `true` without having to change anything else in the code (due to compilation errors).